# Infinitive or conjugated verb

Tags: infinitives, conjugations

I got in a doubt when writing a sentence and I would like your help to understand which one is correct. The sentence is:

1 - It is essential that everyone is aware of the project's aims and purpose.

2 - It is essential that everyone be aware of the project's aims and purpose.

Is the second phase correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! You've got a great answer already, but in the future, please include *why* you have uncertainty about a certain usage, so we can address your concern directly.

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) four correct ways to say this:

- It is essential for everyone to be aware of the project's aims and purpose.
- It is essential that everyone is aware of the project's aims and purpose.
- It is essential that everyone should be aware of the project's aims and purpose.
- It is essential that everyone be aware of the project's aims and purpose.

The last one doesn't technically use an infinitive but a subjunctive. However, the subjunctive is always identical to the bare infinitive.

Comment: And, to anticipate the follow-up question: For all practical purposes, all four "mean" the same thing. Any distinctions in meaning are slight.

Comment: what if I change 'be aware' for 'get knowledge'. Would the subjunctive still work?
For example: 
It is essential that everyone get knowledge of the project's aims and purpose?; or
It is essential that everyone gets knowledge of the project's aims and purpose?

Are both correct too?

Comment: @LeanKervi Yes, both are correct.